# shared cache on PDO sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Im trying to make a temporary db with PDO and sqlite as driver since official documentation shows:

> `rc = sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db)`

how i can implement this in php PDO?

I have this starting code:

```
$db = new PDO( 'sqlite::memory:', 
                null, 
                null, 
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true )
              );
```

how i can implement the shared memory?
adding `?cache=shared` after `sqlite::memory:` fails.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check PDO documentation for this feature?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes but I can't found anything, or is undocumented.

Comment: if ist' not documented, it's probably not documented. I am also curious, if you really need that cache.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the cache in memory reads/write really fast compared to default's file read/write.

Comment: @YourCommonSense cache works with above code, what im trying to do is tell my script wich temporary db read/write since is URI based.

Comment: Nascar racing car is *really* fast compared to conventional pickup. Which one you'd take to go fishing? I know that memory reads are faster. I am curious if you really need that.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I'm writting an app wich read/write (really a lot) a lot just a few lines and then, the data, is no longer need, so I don't need a static db wich makes the main script slower, (file/temp db speed: .1xxx vs .003 secs ) a mysql db is not an option since data will be deleted after and needs to setup.